# Updating user's phone and fax number from visual force page

Tags: visualforce, standardcontroller

```
          <apex:page standardController="user" >
         <apex:form >
             <table>
                   <tr>
                <td>
                    First Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputlabel value="{!$User.FirstName}">
                    </apex:outputlabel>
                </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                <td>
                    Last Name
                </td>
                <td>
                    :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputlabel value="{!$User.LastName}">
                    </apex:outputlabel>
                </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td>
                    Email
                </td>
                <td>
                    :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:outputlabel value="{!$User.Email}">
                    </apex:outputlabel>
                </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                <td>
                    Phone
                </td>
                <td>
                    :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!User.Phone}"/>
                </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                <td>
                    Fax
                </td>
                <td>
                    :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <apex:inputText value="{!User.Fax}"/>

                </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>


                <td>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
                </td>
                     </tr>
             </table>
         </apex:form>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Can you help me where is the problem ? It doesnt give an error but it just wont update user profile.

Comment: asking the same, where is the problem?

Comment: It doesnt update user's phone number and fax. Thats the problem. Can i do this by using standartcontroller or do i have to write my owncontroller ?

Comment: @Emir Please try to explain the problem next time. The code won't do any good to us unless we have a context.

Yes, It can be done via standard controller

Comment: Consider these Emir, 1)use `{!$User.FIELD_NAME}`, your are missing `$` sign. 2). Make sure your URL is having a valid user record id. 3). Add a `<apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>` inside your pageblock so that any errors will be displayed.

Comment: Well i try to update curreny logged in user details. Do i need to point user id in url ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update user details but you are using the global $USER everywhere.

Try this.

Make sure the id is appended to URL in the visual-force as a parameter.

> https://c.**INSTANCE**.visual.force.com/apex/**YOURPAGENAME**?id=005XXXXXXXXXXXX

```
    <apex:page standardController="user" >
   <apex:pageBlock title="Kullanıcı Bilgileri" mode="edit">
      <style>
         .lookupIcon 
         {
         display:none;
         }
      </style>
      <apex:form >
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  First Name
               </td>
               <td>
                  :
               </td>
               <td>
                  <apex:outputlabel value="{!User.FirstName}">
                  </apex:outputlabel>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Last Name
               </td>
               <td>
                  :
               </td>
               <td>
                  <apex:outputlabel value="{!User.LastName}">
                  </apex:outputlabel>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Email
               </td>
               <td>
                  :
               </td>
               <td>
                  <apex:outputlabel value="{!User.Email}">
                  </apex:outputlabel>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Phone
               </td>
               <td>
                  :
               </td>
               <td>
                  <apex:inputText value="{!User.Phone}"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Fax
               </td>
               <td>
                  :
               </td>
               <td>
                  <apex:inputText value="{!User.Fax}"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </apex:form>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can you help me how can i add id to url.

Comment: How will the user reach this page? Is there a button or something?

Comment: right now there is nothing. accessing by direct link.

Comment: How are you planning it to happen? You can make a Custom-link or button which opens a VF page. Lots of ways